In Owlready2 how to merge the classes of one ontology with those of another?
I am asking how to do something similar to what is unsuccessfully attempted here:
https://github.com/pwin/owlready2/issues/22
Reading the Owlready documentation it seems like:
onto.imported_ontologies.append(owlready_ontology)
would permit onto to access owlready_ontology to somehow manipulate it. How can this be done?
